# On The Question of A Squeeze-Derivative Definition

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Question:** Find $g'(0)$ where $$g(x)=\left(x+1\right)^2 \left(1+\cos{\left(\sqrt{|\tan{(x+1)}|}\right)}\right)+\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}\left(1-\cos{\left(\sqrt{|\tan{(x+1)}|}\right)}\right).$$
The above question was asked by my professor as an exam question. When I was in the exam, I remember doing the following operations; I wanted to use some kind of linear approximation of $L(x)$ so around $a=0$; $\cos{x}\approx 1$ but somehow this operation is valid when the interior of the $\cos$ function approaches zero. I think I could use this: $$-1 \leq \cos{\left(\sqrt{|\tan{(x+1)}|}\right)} \leq 1,$$ $$0\leq 1-\cos{\left(\sqrt{|\tan{(x+1)}|}\right)}\leq 2,$$ $$0\leq \sqrt{x^4+4x+1}\left(1-\cos{\left(\sqrt{|\tan{(x+1)}|}\right)}\right) \leq 2\sqrt{x^4+4x+1},$$ and note that: $$0 \leq (x+1)^2\left(1+\cos{\left(\sqrt{|\tan{(x+1)}|}\right)}\right)\leq 2(x+1)^2;$$ so,
$$0 \leq g(x) \leq 2(x+1)^2+2\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}.$$
Now, I feel that I should use some kind of derivative definition here, as given in the hint in the exam, but I can't reach the conclusion.

Comment: You are right, $g’(0)=4$. I have just found my false step and corrected it.

Comment: You need to write in your question what you tried, otherwise moderators will close your question very soon and I will not be able to give you an answer containing my calculations. Look at [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/771461) in order to learn to ask a good question.

Comment: Please, look at [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/771461), read it and improve your question in order to avoid moderators closing it ! If you improve your question, I will be able to write an answer about the calculations for obtaining the result of $g’(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;g_1(x)=x^2+2x+1+\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}\;.$

Let $\;g_2(x)=\left[x^2\!+\!2x\!+\!1\!-\!\sqrt{x^4\!+\!4x\!+\!1}\right]\cos\left(\!\sqrt{|\tan(x+1)|}\right).$

It results that

$\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}x=\dfrac{g_1(x)-g(0)}x+\dfrac{g_2(x)}x\;.$

$\dfrac{g_1(x)-g(0)}x=\dfrac{x^2+2x+1+\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}-2}x=$

$=\dfrac{x^2+2x}x+\dfrac{\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}-1}x=$

$=x+2+\dfrac{x^4+4x+1-1}{x\left(\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}+1\right)}=$

$=x+2+\dfrac{x^3+4}{\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}+1}\to2+\dfrac42=4\;\;$ as $\;\;x\to0\;.$

Moreover ,

$\dfrac{g_2(x)}x=\dfrac{\left[x^2\!+\!2x\!+\!1\!-\!\sqrt{x^4\!+\!4x\!+\!1}\right]\cos\left(\!\sqrt{|\tan(x+1)|}\right)}x=$

$=\dfrac{\left[\left(x^2+2x+1\right)^2-x^4-4x-1\right]\cos\left(\sqrt{|\tan(x+1)|}\right)}{x\left(x^2+2x+1+\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}\right)}=$

$=\dfrac{\left(4x^3+6x^2\right)\cos\left(\sqrt{|\tan(x+1)|}\right)}{x\left(x^2+2x+1+\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}\right)}=$

$=\dfrac{\left(4x^2+6x\right)\cos\left(\sqrt{|\tan(x+1)|}\right)}{x^2+2x+1+\sqrt{x^4+4x+1}}\;.$

Hence ,

$0\leqslant\left|\dfrac{g_2(x)}x\right|\leqslant\dfrac{\left|4x^2+6x\right|}{x^2\!+\!2x\!+\!1+\!\sqrt{x^4\!+\!4x\!+\!1}}\to0\;\;$ as $\;\;x\to0\,.$

Consequently ,

$\dfrac{g_2(x)}x\to0\;\;$ as $\;\;x\to0\;.$

Therefore ,

$\begin{align}g’(0)&=\lim_\limits{x\to0}\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}x=\lim_\limits{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{g_1(x)-g(0)}x+\dfrac{g_2(x)}x\right)=\\
&=4+0=4\;.\end{align}$